# Select from multiply sockets - right NFDS value?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I think that NFDS in **select()** determines how many sockets the function will check in READFDS and the other `fd_set`s. So if we set 3 sockets in our `fd_set`, but I want to check only first one, I have to call select(1 + 1,...). Is this right?

Or does "*nfds is the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1*" in [linux select man](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) means something different? Also why do we need to add + 1?

**Example code - fixed**

```
int CLIENTS[max_clients];//Clients sockets

int to_read;
FD_ZERO(&to_read);

int i;
int max_socket_fd = 0;

for (i = 0 ; i < max_clients ; i++)
{
 if(CLIENTS[i] < 0)
    continue;

 int client_socket = CLIENTS[i];
 if(client_socket > max_socket_fd)
    max_socket_fd = client_socket;
 FD_SET(client_socket , &to_read);
}

struct timeval wait;

wait.tv_sec = 0;
wait.tv_usec = 1000;

int select_ret = select(max_socket_fd + 1, &read_flags, NULL, NULL, &wait);
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"*nfds is the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1*"

Every file descriptor is represented by an **integral value**. So they are not asking for the `x-th` descriptor that you want to check, they are asking for the **highest integral value** of the descriptors in your `READFDS` +1.

Btw, you should check out [`poll(2)` and `ppoll(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html).

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> int select_ret = select(current_clients + 1, &read_flags, NULL, NULL, &wait);
> ```

Your code is wrong. You don't need to pass the number of file descriptors monitored. You need to pick the biggest descriptor you're interested in and add 1.

[The standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pselect.html) says:

> The nfds argument specifies the range of descriptors to be tested. The
>   first nfds descriptors shall be checked in each set; that is, the
>   descriptors **from zero through nfds-1** in the descriptor sets shall be
>   examined

So it's just the expected semantics of `select`: `nfds` is not the number of file descriptors (as its name would imply) but rather the upper limit of the watched range.

The bold part in the quote also explains why you need to add 1 to your `nfds`.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, the "fd" you put into the FD_SET() and similar calls are integer numbers. The "nfds" required by select is the max() of all these values, plus 1.